# Sou novo em programação, como consigo obter saida dos retornos de foma sequencial?

Tags: python, funções

```
ano = input()  
a= ano.split()
def contaDigitos():
for x in a:
    s= len(x)
    if s !=4:
     return "Ano invalido"
    else:
     return x

def ehBissexto():
for x in a:
    x= int(x)
    if x % 4==0 and x %100!=0:
     if x> 2019:
         return("ser� bisexto")
     else :
         return"foi bisexto"
    else:
        return "nao e bissexto" 

Mensagem (k,m):
print("{}={}".format(k,m))

Mensagem(contaDigitos(),ehBissexto())
```

entrada
2017 2020 1980 05 20 2024

saida esperada
O ano 2017 NAO eh bissexto
O ano 2020 serah bissexto
O ano 1980 foi bissexto
Ano invalido
Ano invalido
O ano 2024 serah bissexto

Comment: O que seria "forma linear" da saída da função? Qual é a saída atual? **Obs.:** verificar a indentação do código na pergunta...

Comment: na forma que está no exemplo da saida acima, (um do lado o outro )

Comment: Marcos, "forma linear" seria todas as saídas na mesma linha?

Comment: O termo correto é saída sequencial. Quando usa termo linear dá a entender que o resultado vem de um transformador linear.

Comment: ok vou alterar a pergunta obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma sugestão de código capaz de resolver o seu problema, veja só:

```
import calendar
import datetime

entrada = input()

agora = datetime.datetime.now()

anos = [(int(ano), calendar.isleap(int(ano))) for ano in entrada.split()]

for ano, ehbissexto in anos:
    bissexto = ' ' if ehbissexto else ' nao '
    if ano > agora.year:
        print('O ano de {}{}serah bissexto.'.format(ano,bissexto))
    elif ano < agora.year:
        print('O ano de {}{}foi bissexto.'.format(ano,bissexto))
    elif ano == agora.year:
        print('O ano de {}{}eh bissexto.'.format(ano,bissexto))
```

Entrada:

```
1982 1983 1984 1985 1990 2018 2019 2020 2021 2022
```

Saída:

```
O ano de 1982 nao foi bissexto.
O ano de 1983 nao foi bissexto.
O ano de 1984 foi bissexto.
O ano de 1985 nao foi bissexto.
O ano de 1990 nao foi bissexto.
O ano de 2018 nao foi bissexto.
O ano de 2019 nao eh bissexto.
O ano de 2020 serah bissexto.
O ano de 2021 nao serah bissexto.
O ano de 2022 nao serah bissexto.
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ElegantDeeppinkRevisioncontrol)